# random numbers intervals based on checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I’m new to both Laravel and php. Need some help with generating random numbers.

- If checkbox 1 (exercise_choice_10) is selected a random number between 1-10 shall be generated.
- If checkbox 2 (exercise_choice_20) is selected a random number between 11-20 shall be generated.
- If checkbox 3 (exercise_choice_30) is selected a random number between 21-30 shall be generated.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_10" value="10" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_10') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 1</input></BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_20" value="20" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_20') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 2</input></BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_30" value="30" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_30') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 3</input></BR>
```

```
<form action="{{ route('exam.robot', ['course' => $course]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_10" value="10" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_10') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 1</input></BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_20" value="20" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_20') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 2</input></BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="exercise_choice_30" value="30" {{ app('request')->input('exercise_choice_30') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Type 3</input></BR>
    </BR>
    <button class="button">Submit</button>
    </BR>
    </BR>
    {{ $random }}
</form>
```

Comment: By this logic, you can have all 3 checked at the same time - what happens then?

Comment: You may want a radio button here instead of a checkbox, and is what you need just 'how to make random number in php' -- there are a LOT of hits on https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+random+numbers

Comment: Thank you for your reply Qirel :) This solution (see below) did only work with radiobuttons. When using checkbox the last checked checkbox will override the rest. So Im still working on a solution for checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you can check if the checkbox was checked, and use the `value` from that checkbox. We know from your examples that the range will be between `$value - 9` and `$value`.

We can use `rand($min, $max)` to get the random value.

```php
if ($request->has("exercise_choice_10")) {
    $value = $request->input("exercise_choice_10");
    $randomValue = rand($value-9, $value);
}
```

Repeat the same for your other checkboxes and return the `$randomValue` to your view.

Keep in mind, by using checkboxes, all 3 can be checked at any given time - so you may want radio-buttons instead (where only one per name can be checked).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Qirel
This solution (see below) did only work with radiobuttons. When using checkbox the last checked checkbox will override the rest. So Im still working on a solution for checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply Qirel :) 
This solution (see below) did only work with radiobuttons. When using checkbox the last checked checkbox will override the rest. So Im still working on a solution for checkbox.

```
if ($request->input('exercise_choice_10')) {
    $value = $request->input("exercise_choice_10");
    $random = rand($value-9, $value);
}
else {
}
if ($request->input('exercise_choice_20')) {
    $value = $request->input("exercise_choice_20");
    $random = rand($value-9, $value);
}
else {
}

if ($request->input('exercise_choice_30')) {
    $value = $request->input("exercise_choice_30");
    $random = rand($value-9, $value);
}
else {
}
```

Comment: Don't post answers like that, edit it into your question instead. That said, you need to define some logic with the checkboxes - will you return all 3 random values? If not, how do you determine WHICH ONE of the values from the checkboxes you should return?